# Issues with Adding Verified Caller IDs in Twilio Sandbox for Different Countries

Tags: numbers, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, caller-id

In the context of a Twilio sandbox account created for India, there's a need to add verified caller IDs. The process works smoothly when adding Indian numbers to the verified caller IDs list; however, problems arise when attempting to add a Liberian number. Specifically, after adding the Liberian number to the verified caller IDs, the verification code is not received by the client. This situation prevents the addition of the client's number for testing purposes.

Has anyone encountered similar issues with adding verified caller IDs for different countries in the Twilio sandbox account? Is there any insight or solution available for this problem?